# Is styling a:visited in the shadow-root from outside the custom element not supported?

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

In a parent element, I've got:

```
safe-html::shadow a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(34, 110, 223);
}

safe-html::shadow a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

safe-html::shadow a:visited {
  color: rgb(106, 56, 223);
}
```

For some reason, the `a:visited` color isn't being respected, even though Chrome says it is being applied. The `a` and `a:hover` work fine, though.

Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/1kFHk

Comment: This is working for me. http://jsbin.com/jitic/1/edit

Comment: Me too. Hrm, and my issue went away somehow. Maybe a temporary Chrome thing? Will keep an eye out. Thank you!